# Images not showing on website. suspect www-data issue

Tags: apache2

I have an issue with website not showing images but loading the rest of the page.

(1) The image path is shown correctly when I inspect element from chrome:

```
img src="/var/www/html/xxx/public_html/Splash_logo_bg.png"
```

(2) The image file permissions seem to be set correctly:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 17661 Feb  3 02:16 /var/www/html/xxx/public_html/Splash_logo_Bg.png
```

(3) The Apache2 directories seem to be set correctly:

```
Directory /var/www/html/xxx.com/
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
/Directory

Directory /usr/share
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
/Directory

Directory /var/www/html/xxx.com/
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
```

(4) setting permissions for www-data:

```
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/html/xxx.com
sudo chmod o-rwx /var/www/html/xxx.com

No such file or directory
```

(5) A few days ago I transferred some files from windows to ubuntu 18.04 directory

```
/var/www/html/xxx.com/public_html/
```

To do this I modified the root password for ubuntu as I was getting a permission error when trying to transfer the files.

I think this may have broken the `www-data` file. Can anyone advise on how to check this or repair it?

Note that this is a locally hosted test server (not in production) so I am not concerned about security but looking for a quick fix that will allow me to test a new website under construction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The URL to the images should not follow the Linux path but the path, relative to web site home. So your line:

```
img src="/var/www/html/xxx/public_html/Splash_logo_bg.png"
```

must be

```
img src="/public_html/Splash_logo_bg.png"
```

or maybe

```
img src="/Splash_logo_bg.png"
```

Check the config of apache.

Comment: Thx for advice. I have changed the config of HTML and verified in chrome inspect element. img src="/public_html/Splash_logo_bg.png" Problem still persists.

Comment: @ElliottFarmer, check in access, error log what you have and add the result in question

Comment: I reloaded the website page with the missing splash_logo at 19:12 04/02/2019.
Then performed the below command and I do not see any logs with the time stamp above.

efarmer@vmbth:~$ sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Tue Feb 04 06:25:01.413113 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2778] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 04 06:25:01.413126 2020] [core:notice] [pid 2778] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: In place of the disired image, I have a small logo/icon appearing where the image should be. The icon/logo is that of an image with top right the corner folded over, a green semi circle at the bottom and a diagonal line through the bottom right corrner.

I have tested this webpage locally on the laptop I used to create it and the image loads fine so I do not believe the bmp file to be corrupted. The issue only persists when I transfer the htm, ccs and bpm to the server. Note that the src in the html is corrected to reflect its location on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved. Or more correctly I have found a workaround. Instead of building my lamp stack manually with Ubuntu, apache, MariaSQL & PHP I have just installed XAMPP. THis is displaying png images fine.